# Android Studio with Galaxy S7 - Android 7.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to debug with Androd Studio 2.3.1 an app (min sdk 16, target sdk 24) with a Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 7.0 installed), but I get the following exception and the app stops:

```
com.venework.app.venework E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.venework.app.venework, PID: 3556
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.venework.app.venework/com.venework.app.venework.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.venework.app.venework.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.venework.app.venework.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.venework.app.venework-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

If I test with any other device everything is ok... any hint ? I have run out of options. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

The splash-screen image was in the wrong folder. drawable instead of drawable-xxhdpi... really a stupid problem.... with devices with low resolution displays it didn't make any difference, but with a high-res display like that of the Samsung S7 is completely another story...